# simpler implementation for matcher option of select2

Tags: jquery-select2

current:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
  $(".js-example-matcher-start").select2({
    matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
  })
});
```

could we make it simple by removing the oldMatch() and the require part:

```
$(".js-example-matcher-start").select2({
    matcher: matchStart
  })
```

(we move the call to oldMatch internally inside select2.js)

or could we separate the require part something like this:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], ...);

$(".js-example-matcher-start").select2({
    matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
  })
```

thanks